# Illegal character U+200B android

Tags: java, android, illegal-characters

i'll Follow below links but didn't help for me :

- [Illegal Character error: '\u200b'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657620/illegal-character-error-u200b)

Whenever i add below code :

```
// get our folding cell
        final FoldingCell fc = (FoldingCell) findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);
​
        // attach click listener to folding cell
        fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fc.toggle(false);
            }
        });
```

This Error Comes : `Illegal character U+200B`

Error is not show on `Logcat` or `massage` it's show in `MainActivity.class` at the below `findviewById`

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.foldingcell.MainActivity">

    <com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/folding_cell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        >
        ​
    </com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>

</LinearLayout>
```

I copy code from hear: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3426

Comment: can u share your whole logcat error / layout and activity code

Comment: in `Logcat` can't show me any error

Comment: *i'll Follow below links but didn't help for me* - I copied your code, got the same error, deleted the blank line and then it worked. I can't imagine it would not work for you. Tell me why I should not close the question as duplicate, why did it not work for you?

Comment: i already tried that really it's can't work for me @TimCastelijns

Comment: what did you do? Did you cut the line and then paste it back or something? If you just delete the line it is impossible that the error is still there

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but paste it if you like

Comment: `\u200B` is a zero-width space. Deleting, rewriting from fresh - as said - is the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an invisible character on the third line. Delete the line manually and add it again using the keyboard.

Try replacing your code with this one:

```
// get our folding cell
    final FoldingCell fc = (FoldingCell) findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);

    // attach click listener to folding cell
    fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fc.toggle(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: he claims he already tried that

Comment: How?  Because he has removed the bad character!!

Comment: I deleted the third line entirely and then add it back using the enter button from my keyboard

Comment: Let's move this discussion to the chat room I have just created https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174336/u200b-discussion