# React Native Runtime Error: No native client found. Is Bugsnag React Native installed in your native code project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bugsnag

I am trying to integrate bugsnag to my react native application. The app builds successfully but when the app loads on a simulator or emulator it throws an exception

```
Bugsnag: No native client found. Is BugsnagReactNative installed in your native code project?
Client

<unknown>
    global.js:4:27
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    index.android.js:9
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:197:45
global code
```

I have updated my AndroidManifest.xml, MainApplication.java, Info.plist, build.gradle to include the api-key and bugsnag-react-native was successful too.

my package.json versions look like

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.2",
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
               android:value="API KEY"/>
```

MainApplication.java

```
@Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BugsnagReactNative.start(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
```

info.plist

```
<key>BugsnagAPIKey</key>
<string>API KEY</string>
```

Comment: Having same issue

Comment: @PhilAndrews in your settings.gradle under android 
add the automatically generated import when you did the link from terminal under 
`
include ':app'
include ':bugsnag-react-native'
project(':bugsnag-react-native').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/android')

`

make sure you have binaries linked in your Xcode 
`
libz.tbd and 
libBugsnagReactNative.a
`
inside your mainapplication.java add the line below under the packages object
`
new MainReactPackage(), BugsnagReactNative.getPackage()
`
That should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you did react-native link bugsnag-react-native.
Then you will need following changes if you are having this issue. I found the solution.

In you Android/settings.gradle put the `include bugsnag-react-native` under `include ':app'`

```
include ':app'
include ':bugsnag-react-native'
project(':bugsnag-react-native').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/android')
```

make sure you have binaries linked in your Xcode. To do so select your project in Xcode, click build phases, link binary with libraries and add the following libraries. To manually import bugsnag-react-native from node_modules in Xcode follow the link below

```
libz.tbd and 
libBugsnagReactNative.a
```

In your `MainApplication.java` add the line in getPackages()

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
new MainReactPackage(), BugsnagReactNative.getPackage()
```

That should do the work.

Bugsnag Docs
[Manual linking](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/manual-linking-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

From [Bugsnag Basic Configuration](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/#basic-configuration), you are missing the following:

> Import and initialize Bugsnag within your app’s entry point, typically
>   index.js (or index.ios.js and index.android.js):

```
import { Client } from 'bugsnag-react-native';
const bugsnag = new Client('YOUR-API-KEY-HERE');
```

You don't need to have the key value in the `info.plist` file unless you are loading the value from there (which I think you are not)

Comment: I have already done that just forgot to add it to the question.

Comment: On what platform are you having this issue? Android or iOS?

Comment: Did you add `BugsnagReactNative.getPackage()` inside `getPackages()` in your MainApplication?

Comment: On both platforms

Comment: Adding BugsnagReactNative.getPackage() wont build the app

Comment: illegal character: '\u200b'
        BugsnagReactNative.getPackage()​
I get this error during build when i add 
BugsnagReactNative.getPackage() inside getPackages()

Comment: Check this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657620/illegal-character-error-u200b

Answer (score 0):

In your MainApplication.java, you may need to add the following to the top section of the file:

```
import com.bugsnag.BugsnagReactNative;
```