# Remove "\u200b" in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I have copied a piece of code from Microsoft Teams. And when run, it crashes.

Here is information about the error:

[image]

The red dot characters it is "\u200b". I re-checked the IDE (VS Code) and didn't see this.

How to remove it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does a find `\u200b` and replace with nothing work?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404257/836330